# How to load function after ajax load all DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with a function that should be loaded after all content is ready.
I have a massive ajax call 1700 line of code.

***How my code works:*** php file getting data from 3 tables in my database and converting it to JSON. I opening the JSON file and creating 1 element for 1 database result.

For now, I have around 100 results but I will have around 1000 in the final step. So I create loading to put before the page will be loaded. But because the main content is created by js, sometimes my loading fade out 1-2 sec before content is loaded. I can use js or jquery. For now, I used something like that :

```
$(window).on ('load', function (){
     setTimeout(function (){
     $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');}, 1000)});
```

Comment: what is it you are waiting for exactly? window.onload (essentially what you're doing) fires once the page is loaded - why do you need to wait longer if what you want is to wait for window load?

Comment: Ye schould do but... few times when page was tested, loading hides before ajax create dom elements so for 1 sec we had empty page

Comment: oh, so you're waiting for AJAX to complete - you don't SHOW any ajax in the code in the question ... ajax usually has a success callback - do what you need in that

Comment: Ye usually... I using ajax to read file... so my code look so similar   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { my code goes here
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "somefile.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

Comment: how about you show that *in the question* where it a) makes sense, and b) is readable

Answer (score 1):

Execute the function once you received data through AJAX. Check the code snippet below

```
            $.ajax({
                    url: '/URL/TO/CODE',
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') //This is optional if you are using x-csrf-token validation of if u want to pass any header data
                    },
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        data:data //In case if you need to pass any data
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    before:function(){
                        //Is you want to show any loader or anything while ajax is being executed.
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                       //Once your ajax  is success you can call your custom function to do things with the data
                     myCustomFunction();
                    },
                    error: function (res) {
                        console.log(res);
                    }
                });


       function myCustomFunction(){
          //This to be executed when all data are filled by ajax and page is loaded
       }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ye it will help others with similar problem. but I'm not sure where to use on my ajax code :  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     My code goes here 
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_file.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

Comment: use it in `My code goes here` - note, you tagged your question jquery, so it's natural to **assume** you use jquery **ajax** - that's why it's important to post the code that is relevant to your question *in the question*

Comment: Ye I know. But I did not know that I will need to put that kind of function inside ajax call... so can I put it after xmlhttp.send(); ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).ready(function (){
   setTimeout(function(){ $("#loading").fadeOut('slow'); }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Please format your answer and give better explanation.

Comment: That one will not help me at all. You just change time out. You need to know for future that everything depends from user Internet connection.